# How do I make jQuery to output different DIV-classes?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a script in jQuery that retrieves data from http://pi.codele.se/php/debatt.php (json-formatted). And it's returned in `<div id="output">` inside http://pi.codele.se/debatt.html?page=1. As you can see in the **fetch/fetch.js**, it returns inside a `<div class = "box w-25 h-70 ">`. But I want the code to randomise between five DIV classes.

Ex.

```
<div class="box w-25 h-70">
<div class="box 2">
<div class="box 3">
<div class="box 4">
<div class="box 5">
```

fetch/fetch.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://pi.codele.se/php/debatt.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var content = '<div class="box w-25 h-70"><h3>'+item.rubrik+'<span>Publicerad '+ item.datum+'</span></h3>'
                + '<p>'+item.innehall+'<br></div></div>';       
                output.append(content);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('Kolla din anslutning.')
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('#output');
    var classes = ['box w-25 h-70', 'box2', ...]

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://pi.codele.se/php/debatt.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

                var arr_idx = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length);
                var content = '<div class="' + classes[arr_idx] + '"><h3>'+item.rubrik+'<span>Publicerad '+ item.datum+'</span></h3>'
                + '<p>'+item.innehall+'<br></div></div>';       
                output.append(content);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('Kolla din anslutning.')
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://pi.codele.se/php/debatt.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var content = '<div class="box w-'+i+'h-'+i+1+'"><h3>'+item.rubrik+'<span>Publicerad '+ item.datum+'</span></h3>'
                + '<p>'+item.innehall+'<br></div></div>';       
                output.append(content);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('Kolla din anslutning.')
        }
    });
});
```